# Convert HTML to PDF

Tags: pdf, convert, html

I went through other links with a similar question, but couldn't find a solution that I wanted.

I am trying to provide documentation for my tool in PDF format. I have a bunch of .html files that reference each other using relative address. When I convert it to PDF, these references are not resolved to the pages within the PDF but refer to the .html file which is incorrect.

Are there any tools that achieve this facility, wherein one .html file which refers to other .html file when converted to PDF resolve to right pages within the PDF.

Comment: It would be interesting to find out as I have the same problem

Comment: @Jhondoe Check out htmldoc. This gives all the references correctly. I am yet figure out how to get colors from html file to the PDF. Everything is in black and white!